# How do I format my Nexus 5's /sdcard volume?

Tags: recovery-mode, file-system, internal-sd, formatting, nexus-5

I have an encrypted Nexus 5, and I want to format `/sdcard` as ext4 so I can use symbolic links. What steps should I take to back up and restore it, and to prevent apps from trying to use it before it's ready (e.g. using the Android equivalent of single-user mode)?

I've rooted my Nexus and unlocked the bootloader, but I haven't installed a custom ROM or anything else—it's still running stock Android.

Comment: It's already an ext4 filesystem. `/data/media/0` is basically [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) mounted to `/sdcard` (in reality there's some more indirection going on, since `/sdcard` itself is a link).

Comment: @eldarerathis Hmm…any idea why `ln -s` gives me `link failed Function not implemented`, then?

Comment: @BlacklightShining, that would probably have something to do with the fact that it's FUSE mounted.